# SQL Convert list STRING into list NUMERIC

Tags: sql, type-conversion, numeric, varchar

I have this very simple Query with SQL

```
SELECT * FROM DB_TEST WHERE ID in ('3','4','6','7')
```

And I would like convert the list into numeric value, like (3,4,6,7), do you know what is the process to change this ?

The ID columns accept only the numeric value.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you drop the single quotes, or am I missing something? Are you trying to send the values in as a singular value with a variable?

Comment: Hello, yes I can. But I try to use replace() with in and is not work. Do you have an example to replace the simple quote and use in ?

Comment: Can you paste the query you're having trouble with? As in, what you've tried that isn't working. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you're after.

Comment: SELECT * FROM DB_TEST WHERE ID in (3,4,6,7), this is my result that I would like. I don’t  want to have the simple quote

Comment: What errors do you get when you run that query?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is if it is possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_TEST WHERE ID in 
replace(('3','4','6','7'), "'", "")
```

If this is the question then the answer is no - or at least not if you want to use standard SQL functions.

Obviously you could write a stored procedure to do this but I'm not sure why anyone would go to the effort. It would take about 5 seconds to manually edit the example you've given, or do a find-and-replace using your code/text editor